# Convert.ToInt32 is not in correct format

Tags: vb.net, winforms, error-handling, type-conversion

This line of code is used to enter an item's quantity into my database:

```
ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", Convert.ToInt32(txtCount.Text))
```

It used to work but now im having this error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: What values of `txtCount.Text` is it giving an error on? I am guessing those that are strings that do not represent integer values.

Comment: im sorry i did not understand your comment. excuse me for not understaning im new at coding.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` will try to convert the passed in string to an integer, that is, a whole number. If the passed in string is not made up just of numbers (say it is "abc" or "123d" or "123.45"), the conversion will fail with the error you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the string you're trying to parse an integer from doesn't actually contain a valid integer.

Verify the value of "**txtCount.Text**"

Answer (score 2):

You are better to use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) instead of `Convert`. It will return false if conversion didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are entering wrong values in the txtCount.Text, may be string values. So is there  any restriction to not enter any other value than integer value on that textbox?